# A right-continuous uniformly integrable martingale $(X_t)_{t\in I}$ is closable at $\sup I$

Tags: probability-theory, martingales

Let $X:\Omega\times[0,\infty)\to\mathbb R$ be a right-continuous uniformly integrable martingale on a filtered probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal A,(\mathcal F_t)_{t\ge0}\operatorname P)$ and $(t_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq[0,\infty)$ be nondecreasing with $t_n\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}\infty$.

> Why can we find an $X_\infty\in L^1(\operatorname P)$ with $X_{t_n}\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}X_\infty$ almost surely? And why does this $X_\infty$ not depend on $(t_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$?

Clearly, since $X$ is uniformly integrable, $(X_{t_n})_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is $L^1$-bounded and hence there is some increasing $(n_k)_{k\in\mathbb N}\subseteq\mathbb N$ with $n_k\to\infty$ and some $\tilde X_\infty$ with $\left\|\tilde X_\infty-X_{t_{n_k}}\right\|_{L^1}\xrightarrow{k\to\infty}0$. But that doesn't yield the claim.

Comment: Is there a typo in your conditions on $(t_n)$? Currently the conditions imply $t_n = 0$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: @nobody Thank you, I'd intended to write $t_n\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}\infty$.

Comment: This is Doob's Martingale Convergence Theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $X_{t_n}$ is an $L^1(P)$-bounded discrete time martingale with respect to the filtration $(\mathcal{F}_{t_n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$. So by the discrete time Martingale Convergence Theorem there is $X_{\infty} \in L^1(P)$ such that $X_{t_n} \to X_{\infty}$ almost surely. (And in fact since $(X_{t_n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is uniformly integrable this limit is also in $L^1$-norm)

We are left to check that this limit doesn't depend on choice of the sequence $(t_n)$. Given an alternative such sequence $(s_n)$ form the sequence $(\tilde{t}_n)$ by putting the set $\{s_n \mid n \in \mathbb{N} \} \cup \{t_n \mid n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ in nondecreasing order.

$(\tilde{t}_n)$ has the same properties as $(t_n)$ so as above, $X_{\tilde{t}_n} \to \tilde{X}_\infty$ almost surely for some $\tilde{X}_\infty$. But since the subsequence $X_{t_{n}} \to X_\infty$ almost surely we have $\tilde{X}_\infty = X_\infty$ almost surely.

Comment: I don't understand your argumentation: You've shown that for a specific $(t_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ with $t_n\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}t$, there is a $X_\infty\in L^1(\operatorname P)$ with $X_{t_n}\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}X_\infty$. Now, in order to show that $X_\infty$ doesn't depend on $(t_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$, we should need to show that if $(s_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ with $s_n\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}t$, then $X_{s_n}\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}X_\infty$ almost surely.

Comment: But you've only shown that if $(\tilde t_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq[0,\infty)$ contains $(t_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ as a subsequence, then $X_{\tilde t_n}\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}X_\infty$ almost surely.

Comment: $X_{s_n}$ is a subsequence of $X_{\tilde{t}_n}$ (up to maybe dropping some repetitions of entries in $(s_n)$ which we may clearly do wlog) so if $X_{\tilde{t}_n} \to X_\infty$ then so does $X_{s_n}$.

Comment: It may be clearer if I abstract away the martingale stuff. The idea of that argument is if a sequence $(a_n)$ has as subsequences $(b_n)$ and $(c_n)$ and $a_n \to a$ then $b_n, c_n \to a$ also.

Comment: Why do you think that (without your wlog-assumption) consecutive duplicates of entries in $(s_n)$ are an issue? (Oh, and it should read "But since the subsequence $X_{\color{red}{t}_n} \to X_\infty$ almost surely")

Comment: They aren't really. It's just that the way I've defined $\tilde{t}_n$ has already dropped these duplicates simply because that's the first thing that came to mind when trying to write down the sequence I was thinking of. If you define $\tilde{t}_n$ to contain these duplicates then you can forget my wlog assumption. (and yes, I will edit my answer. Thank you)